# Alternatives to Pattern Fill with Alignment Function

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, alignment, loops, pattern

It is well documented that the origin position of a TikZ pattern cannot easily be changed as the pattern is essentially drawn on an invisible canvas behind all the elements so that it aligns within each element.

I have written the following for an isometric grid pattern:

```
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\def\isoScale{0.5}

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\patternSize}{\isoScale*2cm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\patternHalfSize}{\isoScale*1cm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\patternHeight}{\isoScale*1.1547005384cm}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\patternSize,\patternHalfSize,\patternHeight]{isometric lines}
    {\pgfpointorigin}
    {\pgfqpoint{\patternSize}{\patternHeight}}
    {\pgfqpoint{\patternSize}{\patternHeight}}
    {
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.15mm}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\patternSize}{\patternHeight}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0cm}{\patternHeight}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\patternSize}{0cm}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\patternHalfSize}{0cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\patternHalfSize}{\patternHeight}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\patternSize}{0cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\patternSize}{\patternHeight}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0cm}{\patternHeight}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
```

and am attempting to fill each of the rectangles below:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[pattern=isometric lines] (0,0) rectangle ++(4,4);
        \fill[pattern=isometric lines] (0.1,-5) rectangle ++(4,4);
        \fill[pattern=isometric lines] (0.2,-5) rectangle ++(4,4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

But importantly such that the fill pattern for each is anchored correctly at the top left corner for each, rather than aligned across each, as it is presently:
[image]

How can we achieve this? Open to using something other than patterns for sure. Long story short this is a MWE and I intend on using this to background fill a tcolorbox.

Comment: You could introduce two additional parameters that represent an *x* and a *y* shift which you specify for each rectangle individually. Maybe you can calculate them somehow – the patterns might be “anchored” to one of the page's corner depending on the output format – or you just guesstimate them and adjust them for each rectangle (but if the picture moves to another position you will need to change them again). **Or:** you use a `path picture` (basically a `clip` on the current path). That doesn't provide the advantages of patterns but also not the disadvantages.

Comment: Thank you, I have seen yes the x y shift argument, but honestly too tedious to get the alignment to be exact as needed. Is there an example somewhere re path picture that you can point me to?

Comment: You can look up [`path picture`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#sec-15.6) in the manual or here on the site. Inside it, you have access to the `path picture bounding box` rectangular node. Its north west anchor is the top left corner of a rectangle around the path. In your trivial case of `rectangle` paths this is just that rectangle itself. Since everything you draw inside the `path picture` is clipped against the path you can overshoot the sides without a problem.

Comment: I changed the `align` tag to `alignment`.  `align` is specific to a multi-line math display environment.